# api-platform normalizer: Convert Entity's Id to a HashId in runtime without persisting

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm working my way through API Platform.
I'm currently trying to implement this
https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php

by following the steps in 
https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/724#issuecomment-398812438

how ever, I'm unable to pass the entity as a whole in my serializer. I can only get the individual properties to be passed through.

**My Entity:**

```
class MyEntity
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text", length=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param $id
 */
public function setId($id): void
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getMessage(): ?string
{
    return $this->message;
}

/**
 * @param string|null $message
 */
public function setMessage(?string $message): void
{
    $this->message = $message;
}
}
```

**services.yaml:**

`'App\Serializer\CommonIdentifierNormalizer':
        tags: [ name: serializer.normalizer ]`

**CommonIdentifierNormalizer:**

```
namespace App\Serializer;

use Hashids\Hashids;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;

class CommonIdentifierNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
 private $normalizer;

public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $objectNormalizer)
{
    $this->normalizer = $objectNormalizer;
}

public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
{
    $hashId = new Hashids('', 7);
    $data = $hashId->encodeHex($object->getId());

    $object->setId($data);

    return $this->normalizer->normalize($object);
}

public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
{
    return is_object($data);
}
}
```

However even the supportsNormalization method fails since only individual properties are being passed.
I would like to make it a global solution, where in all the properties marked as identifiers are normalized and my request accepts hashid's instead of the primary key.
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

As an update. I tried this using the identifier normaliser and denormaliser and it worked perfectly well.

my working example.

services.yaml

```
App\Serializer\CommonIdentifierNormalizer:
    tags: ['serializer.normalizer']
    decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
    arguments:
        $decorated: '@App\Serializer\CommonIdentifierNormalizer.inner'
        $iriConverter: '@ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface'

App\Serializer\CommonIdentifierDenormalizer:
    tags:
        - { name: api_platform.identifier.denormalizer }
```

Denormaliser

```
final class CommonIdentifierDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
/**
 * @param mixed $data
 * @param string $class
 * @param null $format
 * @param array $context
 * @return mixed|object|string
 */
public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    if (is_string($data)) {
        return IdentifierHelper::reverseTransformHashToId($data);
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $data
 * @param string $type
 * @param null $format
 * @return bool
 */
public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
{
    return is_string($data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with JMS Serializer, using `pre_serialize` event.

With this method, the actual ID is excluded from serialization, but we use the event to add a `hashId` attribute to our entity which is not persisted.

Generic trait:

```php
namespace App\Entity\Traits;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

trait HashIdTrait
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getHashId")
     */
    private $hashId;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHashId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->hashId;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $hashId
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setHashId($hashId): self
    {
        $this->hashId = $hashId;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\HashIdTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Entity
{
    use HashIdTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     */
    private $id;

    [...]
```

Serializer event:

```php
namespace App\Serializer\Event;

use App\Entity\Entity;
use App\Service\HashIds;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;

class HashIdEvent implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var HashIds */
    protected $hashIds;

    /** @required */
    public function setHashIds(HashIds $hashIds)
    {
        $this->hashIds = $hashIds;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            [
                'event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
                'class' => Entity::class,
                'method' => 'onPreSerialize',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function onPreSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();
        $entity->setHashId($this->hashIds->encode($entity->getId()));
    }
}
```